# Resharper Go To Decompiled sources shows only metadata

Tags: resharper, visual-studio-2019

I am trying to view decompiled sources using Resharper, however all I see is metadata and no actual implementation. My resharper settings is bellow. I have another PC, where settings are similar, however it works as expected.

Am I missing something?

[image]

Comment: Do you have dotPeek installed? I wonder if decompilation may be dependent on its local symbol server.

Comment: @Lennart yes I do, on both machines

Comment: Any reason you don't want to use dotPeek's symbol server (as the option in the screenshot is not checked)?

Comment: No and it was there by default, but it was not working as well(only metadata shown). I unchecked it just to bring in sync with PC where everything works as expected

Comment: There are also several settings in the VS options (under Debugging) that may affect that (you probably know these, https://referencesource.microsoft.com/setup.html). I found navigation to symbols/decompilation/source-stepping generally somewhat wonky over the years without ever finding a real solution. But after clearing the symbol cache and making sure all these options are correctly set it usually worked. I use dotPeek as a symbol server however.